# “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <” on deploy using Netlify

Tags: caching, build, netlify

I am developping a react application, using Netlify to build & deploy the app automatically on commit. Thing is, whenever a new build is deployed in production, the client faces a blank page with this error:

Opera:
[image]
Firefox:
[image]

This does not happen when the website is loaded for the first time by the navigator, and only happens after a new build. After a few reloads, the issue goes away and the website behaves correctly. Thus I assume this has to do with caching.

Also, I didn’t manage to reproduce the error locally. This only happens after a Netlify deployment.

index.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <title>Sensuba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Manifest.json:

```
{
"short_name": "Sensuba",
"name": "Sensuba",
"icons": [
{
  "src": "favicon.ico",
  "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
  "type": "image/x-icon"
}
],
"start_url": "./index.html",
"display": "standalone",
"theme_color": "#000000",
"background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

index.js, in the /src folder:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import './style/index.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './utility/registerServiceWorker';
import Api from './services/Api'

const api = new Api({ url: 'https://bhtwey7kwc.execute-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/alpha' });

const options = { api }

render(
  <App options={options} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
registerServiceWorker();
```

I know this is kind of a known issue, but I didn’t find how to solve this problem in the others threads.

Website: http://sensuba.netlify.app/

Github: [enter link description here](https://github.com/Sensuba/webapp)

Comment: Any update on this? Looks like you got the site working, what was the issue? Im having the same problem

Comment: I am also looking for some solution to this issue.

Comment: could be that this tag with commas is parsed "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" ?

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution...

Comment: Me too - my app was working a few days ago, and now I can't get it to submit a form to psql - with this error being displayed in the chrome browser console (nothing shows as an issue in vs code)